# Further directions in representations of surface group into a Lie group

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, teichmuller-theory, lorentzian-geometry

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}$I studied  the interpretation of Teichmuller space as a representation space for surface groups in $\PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$.

Now I am planning to study the representations of surface group into a Lie group. So, I am planning to read the book [Lectures on representations of surface groups](https://math.unice.fr/%7Elabourie/preprints/pdf/surfaces.pdf) by F. Labourie. As far I understood that the above said book deals with differential geometric notions like connections, curvature, etc.

Also I think that above said F. Labourie's book *"Lectures on representations of surface groups"* is all about to investigate the local and global geometry of representation space, also involves questions about complex and symplectic structures. Also in the last chapter the author discusses a remarkable formula that gives the symplectic volume of the space of representations when $G$ is compact.

My first question is all about some notes or books where I can study throughly and rigorously about the symplectic structure on a manifold. Please provide references.

$\textbf{UPDATE:}$ I have found that the book "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" by John M. Lee contains a chapter (last) on symplectic manifolds.  I will learn about the symplectic structure on a manifold from that book

Now my second question is about the prospects or future directions of representations of surface groups. Maybe I am asking for interaction between

1. [Lectures on representations of surface groups](https://math.unice.fr/%7Elabourie/preprints/pdf/surfaces.pdf) and [Hyperbolic manifolds and Kleinian groups](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Hyperbolic_Manifolds_and_Kleinian_Groups.html?id=DLAGEBfEgEUC&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y).
2. [Lectures on representations of surface groups](https://math.unice.fr/%7Elabourie/preprints/pdf/surfaces.pdf) and [Anti-de Sitter geometry](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.14414).
3. I have heard that [Lectures on representations of surface froups](https://math.unice.fr/%7Elabourie/preprints/pdf/surfaces.pdf) has a lot of interactions with  geometric structures (thanks to this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4618393/1138886)). Does [Introduction to Hitchin representations](http://flab.perso.math.cnrs.fr/Hitchin/index.html) play a strong key role in the relation between [Lectures on representations of surface groups](https://math.unice.fr/%7Elabourie/preprints/pdf/surfaces.pdf) and geometric structures?
4. Do the geometric properties of representations of surface groups in $\SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $\SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ (or in general $\SL(n, \mathbb{R})$ strongly involve study of hyperbolic manifolds?
5. Are there any relations or interactions between [Lectures on representations of surface groups](https://math.unice.fr/%7Elabourie/preprints/pdf/surfaces.pdf) and geometric structures on low dimensional manifolds, in particular hyperbolic and anti-de Sitter $3$-manifolds?

Actually I am looking for further  directions to study the surface group representations. Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend the book of  Hofer for symplectic  geometry and  symplectic invariants, Hamiltonian dynamics.
https://www.amazon.com/Symplectic-Invariants-Hamiltonian-Dynamics-Birkh%C3%A4user/dp/3034801033